# Find the determinant of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the determinant of the matrix
>   $$M = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
> 3 &0 &0 &2 &0\cr
> -2 &0 &-3 &0 &0\cr
> 0 &2 &0 &0 &2\cr
> 0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1\cr
> 0 &2 &-1 &0 &0
> \end{array}\right].$$

I got the REF and tried to find the solution:
$$M = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
3 &0 &0 &2 &0\cr
0 &2 &0 &0 &2\cr
0 &0 &-3 &4/3 &0\cr
0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1\cr
0 &0 &0 &0 &-14/9
\end{array}\right].$$

And I think $\text{det}(M)$ is
$$ \Bigg[ 3\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ \:0&-3\end{pmatrix}-0\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ \:0&-3\end{pmatrix}+0\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\ \:0&0\end{pmatrix}\Bigg].\begin{pmatrix}-1&-1\\ 0&-\frac{14}{9}\end{pmatrix}=-18\cdot\frac{14}{9}=-28$$

So I want to know which part I am wrong.

Comment: By the way, the correct determinant is $28$.

Comment: Isn't the det of a triangular matrix given by the product of terms in the principal diagonal?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The OP has shown their own work.

Comment: The correct ans is 28. I think I forget to add a minus sign for the REF form. (Since exchange any two row need to add a minus sign) So I keep getting the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}
3 &0 &0 &2 &0\cr
0 &2 &0 &0 &2\cr
0 &0 &-3 &4/3 &0\cr
0 &0 &0 &-1 &-1\cr
0 &0 &0 &0 &-14/9
\end{vmatrix}&=3\begin{vmatrix}2 &0 &0 &2\cr
0 &-3 &4/3 &0\cr
0 &0 &-1 &-1\cr
0 &0 &0 &-14/9
\end{vmatrix}\\&=3\cdot2\begin{vmatrix}-3 &4/3 &0\cr
0 &-1 &-1\cr
0 &0 &-14/9
\end{vmatrix}\\&=3\cdot2\cdot(-3)\begin{vmatrix}-1 &-1\cr
0 &-14/9
\end{vmatrix}\\&=3\cdot2\cdot(-3)\cdot\left(\frac{14}9\right)\\&=\color{red}{-28}\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you explain why $$\begin{pmatrix}\color{red}1&-1\\ 0&-\frac{14}{9}\end{pmatrix}$$ is 1 instead of -1

Answer (score 3):

Since the matrix in the question is a upper triangular matrix, the detrrminant is directly given by the product of terms in the principal diagonal.

$$D=3 \cdot 2 \cdot -3 \cdot -1 \cdot \frac{-14}{9} $$
$$D = -28$$

Comment: Note that you have three minus signs so $D$ must be negative.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have already found an expression of $M$ as an **upper triangular matrix**! So the determinant is just the product of the elements in the diagonal.